# Example of a Non-Regular Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A be any nonempty set with members a, b, c. {A} is a set with member A. So, A and {A} are disjoint and {A} is regular. What is an example of a singleton set that is NOT regular?

Comment: In ZF there are none. It is the 'axiom of regularity'

Answer (score 2):

The [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) ([Mirimanoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitry_Mirimanoff)'s Axiom) says that for every nonempty set $x$ there is an element $y\in x$ such that $x\cap y=\emptyset.$ I'm going to guess that by a "non-regular set" you mean a nonempty set $x$ such that $x\cap y\ne\emptyset$ for each $y\in x.$ (As far as I know this is not standard terminology.)

Clearly, a singleton set $\{x\}$ is non-regular if and only if $x\in x.$ In effect, then, you are asking for an example of a set $x$ such that $x\in x.$

In ZF set theory there are no such sets, because of the Axiom of Regularity. In ZF minus the Axiom of Regularity, the existence of such sets can neither be proved nor disproved. But you did not specify ZF or any particular set theory.

The philosopher [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willard_Van_Orman_Quine) has proposed [set theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) with a universal set $V,$ the set of all sets; since $V$ is a set we have $V\in V,$ so $\{V\}$ is an example of a non-regular set. Also, sets $x$ such that $x=\{x\}$ are called [Quine atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Quine_atoms). I seem to recall that Quine suggested somewhere (sorry, no reference) that the relation $x\in y$ should be understood as set-membership if $y$ is a set, and identity if $y$ is not a set, e.g., a physical object; under this interpretation, any physical object can be consider a solution of the equation $x=\{x\}$ and thus a non-regular singleton.

You may also be interested in [Peter Aczel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Aczel)'s [Anti-Foundation Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom).